# C++ String Length Check

Tags: c++, function, c++11

```
bool fitsKey3(string n) {
    int ncheck = str.length(n);
    if (ncheck = KEY3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above function uses a string "n" that is a string given to the function from an input file. I want to write this function that checks the length of this "identifier code" from the input file (it's a drone project), and if the length of the security code is *equal* to the constant integer "KEY3 (= 50), it returns true. Otherwise, return false.

How do I fix this setup?

Comment: Your are using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: `ncheck == KEY3`, `=` and `==` are differemt

Answer (score 4):

`=` assigns the value of `KEY3` to `ncheck`.

`==` compares `ncheck` and `KEY3` for equality.

Also, unless you're being paid by lines of code, I'd suggest using the much simpler and clearer form:

```
return n.length() == KEY3;
```

(I corrected your usage of the `length()` member function, since I suppose it was only a typo.)

And as pointed out by Anon Mail, unless you want to make a copy of the string every time you call the function, I'd suggest only passing a reference to it (`const` because you're not modifying it):

```
bool fitsKey3(string const& n)
```

Comment: I also suggest you pass string n by constant reference (const string & n) instead of by value.  Otherwise you're making an unnecessary copy of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
bool fitsKey3(string n) {
    return n.length() == KEY3;
}
```

You do two operations:

1. Get string length by `n.length()`
2. Compare the length with a KEY3 (NB: use `==` to compare)